# Last Digit of this expression?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation

Came across this Devil while preparing for JEE Advanced.
**Question**: If $$K=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6^n}{(3^n-2^n)(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})}$$
Then the last digit of $(K+6)^{(K+6)!}$ is?

What i tried to do was to separate $6^n$ as $3^n$$2^n$ and tried to proceed further, but to be honest, I'm getting nowhere around the answer which according to my textbook is 8.

Comment: The last digit of that expression is clearly a $6$. It is followed by a closing parenthesis and an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\frac{6^n}{(3^n-2^n)(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})}=\frac{2^n}{3^n-2^n}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}}
$$ giving a telescoping sum, $N\ge1$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{6^n}{(3^n-2^n)(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})}=2-\frac{2^{N+1}}{3^{N+1}-2^{N+1}},
$$ thus we just have
$$
\color{red}{K=2.}
$$

Comment: How did you figured that out!? That first step I mean. Is there any method to do that or it's just observation?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh Your observation $6^n=3^n\times2^n$ and seeing the denominator $(3^n-2^n)(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})$, something clicked.

Comment: Now the question is : how does the book gives $8$ for the last digit ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The last digit is *not* $8$, it is $6$...

Comment: I know and this is why I asked ! So, one more typo in a textbook !

Answer (score 8):

If you really need to see how it telescopes you can do it this way. Take $2^n,2^{n+1} $ common from two brackets now we simplidying we get  $$\frac {1}{2}\frac {3^n}{2^n((\frac {3}{2})^n-1)(\frac {3}{2}(\frac{3}{2})^n-1)} $$ now let $(3/2)^n=a $ we see that $\frac {a}{2}=3\frac {a}{2}-1-(a-1) $ thus the series is $\frac {1}{(\frac {3}{2})^n-1}-\frac{1}{\frac {3}{2}(\frac {3}{2})^n-1} $ thus the sum is $2$